# Overriding ViewChild property in test

Tags: angular, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I've got a component that have ViewChild. I'm using one property from this child in parent component several times, so I need to mock it somehow.

```js
export class ParentComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {
@ViewChild(ChildComponent, { static: true }) private _data: ChildComponent;

ngOnInit(): void {
    console.log(this._data.form)
}

ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    console.log(this._data.form)
}
}
```

Testing without mock results with `TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'form')`

I've tried to assign mock before each test like this:

```js
component['_data'] = { form: formMock} as any;
```

but it results with `Error: NG0100: ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression has changed after it was checked.`

Also tried to use spy, but it's not method so it doesn't really work.

```js
spyOn(component['_data'], 'form').and.returnValue(formMock);
```

`Error: <spyOn> : could not find an object to spy upon for pdForm() Usage: spyOn(<object>, <methodName>)`

Is there any way to mock just one property from ViewChild?

Comment: Here is an excellent article on testing with `ViewChild`: https://indepth.dev/posts/1184/angular-unit-testing-viewchild.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`ng-mocks`](https://ng-mocks.sudo.eu) and [`MockComponent`](https://ng-mocks.sudo.eu/api/MockComponent) along with [`MockInstance`](https://ng-mocks.sudo.eu/api/MockInstance) from it.

```js
// creating a scope for tests
MockInstance.scope();

// mocking dependencies
beforeEach(() => TestBed.configreTestingModule({
  declarations: [
    ParentComponent,
    MockComponent(ChildComponent),
  ],
}).compileComponents());

// customizing mocks and testing
it('test', () => {
  MockInstance(ChildComponent, 'form', {forValue:123});

  const fixture = TestBed.createComponent(ParentComponent);
  fixture.detectChanges();
  // profit
});
```